# importing CSV file with values wrapped in " when some of them contains " as well as commas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, quotes

I think I searched throughout but if I missed something - let me know please.

I am trying to import CSV file where all non numerical values are wrapped with ".
I have encountered a problem with:

```
 df = pd.read_csv(file.csv)
```

Example of CSV:

```
"Business focus","Country","City","Company Name"
"IT","France","Lyon","Societe General"
"Mining","Russia","Moscow","Company "MoscowMining" Owner1, Owner2, Owner3"
"Agriculture","Poland","Warsaw","Company" Jankowski,A,B""
```

Because of multiple quotes and commas inside them, pandas is seeing more columns than 4 in this case (like 5 or 6).

I have already tried to play with

```
df = pd.read_csv(file.csv, quotechar='"', quoting=2)
```

But got

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data (...)
```

What works is skipping bad lines by

```
error_bad_lines=False
```

but I'd rather have all data somehow taken into consideration than just ommit it.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Seems like badly formed CSV file to me. How is this file sourced?

Comment: You may be able to work around the issue by escaping the " which are part of a value. Your best bet might be to assume that a " is only followed by a comma or newline if it is the end of a value. then you could do a regex something like s/"([^,\n])/""$1/g

Comment: unfortunately I was provided with the file and have no influence over how it is prepared by some external systems

Answer (score 2):

This seems like badly formed CSV data as the '"' characters within the values should be escaped. I've often seen such values escaped by doubling them up or prefixing with a \. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#cite_ref-13

First thing I'd do is fix whatever is exporting those files. However if you cannot do that you may be able to work around the issue by escaping the " which are part of a value.

Your best bet might be to assume that a " is only followed (or preceeded) by a comma or newline if it is the end of a value. Then you could do a regex something like (working from memory so may not be 100% - but should give you the right idea. You'll have to adapt it for whatever regex library you have handy)

```
s/([^,\n])"([^,\n])/$1""$2/g
```

So if you were to run your example file though that it would be escaped something like this:

```
"Business focus","Country","City","Company Name"
"IT","France","Lyon","Societe General"
"Mining","Russia","Moscow","Company ""MoscowMining"" Owner1, Owner2, Owner3"
"Agriculture","Poland","Warsaw","Company"" Jankowski,A,B"""
```

or using the following

```
s/([^,\n])"([^,\n])/$1\"$2/g
```

the file would be escaped something like this:

```
"Business focus","Country","City","Company Name"
"IT","France","Lyon","Societe General"
"Mining","Russia","Moscow","Company \"MoscowMining\" Owner1, Owner2, Owner3"
"Agriculture","Poland","Warsaw","Company\" Jankowski,A,B\""
```

Depending on your CSV parser, one of those should be accepted and work as expected.

If, as @exe suggests, your CSV parser also requires the commas within values to be escaped, you can apply a similar regex to replace the commas.

Comment: Made a mistake there- forgot about the preceeding quotes. have adjusted the regex to account for that also. Again I'll note I haven't actually run this

Comment: Also note the above solution will not be perfect. There will be edge cases that will confuse it. The very best (technical, not necessarily practical) solution would probably involve writing a grammar and parser specifically for the csv files exported by your source systems, but even then you may not be able to get around every possible combination without changing the source system.

Comment: Understood. Is there parhaps a way to let pandas know to expect these kind of errors in specific column only (like column4 in my example)? If that would be possible, value "as is", with all weird commas and quotes would be passed and I can work on it further on.

Comment: I don't know pandas but I would be surprised if it did. Having just skimmed the docs (particularly around data import) I can see no obvious option to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well what  you need is cast the quotes and commas before panda read the csv.

Like these:

```
"Business focus","Country","City","Company Name"
"IT","France","Lyon","Societe General"
"Mining","Russia","Moscow","Company \"MoscowMining\" Owner1\, Owner2\, Owner3"
"Agriculture","Poland","Warsaw","Company\" Jankowski\,A\,B\""
```

Comment: As a matter of fact I do not need those external " at all. It would be great to have values kept intact (with all quotes and commas inside).